# How to select the outer <div> around the <input /> field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm doing my first steps with jQuery and need help to choose an appropriate selector for my problem. I have the following HTML in a Django template:

```
{% for field in form %}

    <div class="control-group">

        <label class="control-label" for="{{ field.label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

        <div class="controls">

            {% if field.html_name == "field_1" %}

                <input class="input-xlarge" id="{{ field.label }}" type="text" name="{{ field.html_name }}" />

            {% elif field.html_name == "field_2" %}

                <input class="input-mini" id="{{ field.label }}" type="text" name="{{ field.html_name }}" />

            {% endif %}

        </div>

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I need to do something with the `<input />` fields for which I have the following selectors:

```
var $inputField1 = $('input[name="field_1"]');
var $inputField2 = $('input[name="field_2"]');
```

My problem now is that I need to be able to select a `<div class="control-group"></div>` for a particular `<input />` field in order to change the class of this `<div>`. How do I do that? Do I need the [parent selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) for that? I'm a bit confused. Please help. Thank you very much!

Comment: Deleted django tag since this has nothing to do with Django

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with just a selector. You will need to select the input element as you currently do, and then use the [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the ancestor `div`:

```
var controlGroup = $('input[name="field_1"]').closest('.control-group');
```

Comment: Thank you, the `closest()` method is exactly what I was searching for. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use .closest():

```
var $inputField1 = $('input[name="field_1"]');
var $targetDiv = $inputField1.closest('.control-group');
```

Or use parents():

```
var $inputField1 = $('input[name="field_1"]');
var $targetDiv = $inputField1.parents('.control-group:eq(0)');
```

.closest() is better as it doesn't iterate through all the DOM

Answer (score 2):

Look into jQuery .closest():

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

... If you want a more specific answer, tell us what you want to do with your inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('input[name="field_1"]').parents('.control-group:first')
```